# Adding data to a database and using JSON

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

Im trying to add products to a database on a CMS im making, I want to try and display the products along with their image on another page.

Everything works ok as far as adding the objects to the database but I want the image I upload to be named after the ID of the product within the database, the image is being locally stored in the directory which ill link to later on. Records are being added to the database ok but the image uploader isnt working correctly and im getting the following errors when I submit the form:

My table layout looks like this:

id l name l  quantity l description l  price

---

1  l  key  l   5 l unlocks something    l 6

Notice: Undefined variable: querynew in L:\xampp\htdocs\655487\addSQL.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: querynew in L:\xampp\htdocs\655487\addSQL.php on line 18

Warning: mysqli::query(): Empty query in L:\xampp\htdocs\655487\addSQL.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined variable: querynew in L:\xampp\htdocs\655487\addSQL.php on line 18

This is the form to submit the products with:

```
        <fieldset><legend><span> Add a product to the database </span></legend>

        <form  id ="productsform" method="post" onsubmit="return false;" enctype="multipart/form-data">


        <label> Enter a product name:               <input  type="text"     id="name"           name="name"/>           </label>

        <label> Enter a product quantity:           <input  type="number"   id="quantity"       name="quantity"/>       </label>

        <label> Enter a product description:        <input  type="text"     id="description"    name="description"/>    </label>

        <label> Enter a product price:              <input  type="text"     id="price"          name="price"/>          </label>

        <label> Upload a image of the product:      <input  type="file"     id="file1"          name="file"></label>

        <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" class="reg" value="Add Product">

        <div id="status"></div>
```

here is the script addSQL.php behind it all:

```
 <?php
     include("dbase/config_database.php");

//Stores all information passed through AJAX into the query
$name = $_POST['name'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$price = $_POST['price'];


//Adds information to database
$query = "INSERT INTO products (name, quantity, description, price) VALUES ('$name','$quantity','$description','$price')";
//Runs the query
$result = $mysqli->query($query) OR die("Failed query $query");
echo $mysqli->error."<p>";

$querynew - ("SELECT id as 'collectid' from products WHERE name = '$name'and quantity = '$quantity'and description ='$description'and price = '$price'");
$resultnew = $mysqli->query($querynew) OR die("Failed query $querynew");

while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $resultnew)){
    $productid = $info['collectid'];
}

$image = $_FILES['file1']['name'];
$type = $_FILES['file1']['type'];
$size = $_FILES['file1']['size'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file1']['tmp_name'];

$imgpath = "images/".$productid.".jpg";

// Run the move_uploaded_file() function here
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $imgpath);
// Evaluate the value returned from the function if needed

$querytwo = ("SELECT * FROM products WHERE name = '$name' and quantity = '$quantity' and description = '$description' and price = '$price'");
$resulttwo = $mysqli ->query($querytwo) OR die ("Failed query $querynew");

$info = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulttwo)){
    $product = array("id" => $row ['id'],
        "name" => $row ['name'],
        "quantity" => $row ['quantity'],
        "description" => $row ['description'],
        "price" => $row ['price'],

);

    array_push($info,$product);
}

$json_output = json_encode($info);
echo $json_output;
```

?>

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you be a bit more consistent please? what does this renaming business to do with using JSON?

Comment: there is a `$querynew - ("se...` (on line 17) , shouldn't it be `$querynew = ("se...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo, I have not tested your script other than noticed that

$querynew - ("SELECT id as 'collectid....

Should be

$querynew = ("SELECT id as 'collectid...

This is what your error is, hope it helps

Comment: For those not noticing the difference, the `-` is replaced by `=`